# IntelliJ plugin: How to show multiline inline text

Tags: swing, intellij-plugin

I want to show multiline inline text inside the IntelliJ editors and I have no clue how to implement it and there is no good documentation or examples in the wild.

I try to use the [EditorCustomElementRenderer Interface](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/EditorCustomElementRenderer.java).

I use the [`InlayModel.addBlockElement`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/InlayModel.java) to add/show them.

I can display an inline string just fine, but I want the string to automatically use multiple lines if it is too long.

I try to use a `JBTextArea` to do it, but the problem is that I have no idea how to paint the `textArea`, in the paint function below you can see that I use `drawString`, but I need to draw the whole `textArea`.

Is this somehow achievable?

My class:

```
public class MyClass implements EditorCustomElementRenderer {

    private JBTextArea textArea;
    private Color color;
    public MyClass(final String problemMessage, Color color) {
        textArea = new JBTextArea(problemMessage);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(@NotNull Inlay inlay, @NotNull Graphics graphics, @NotNull Rectangle targetRegion, @NotNull TextAttributes textAttributes) {
        Editor editor = inlay.getEditor();
        EditorColorsScheme colorsScheme = editor.getColorsScheme();

        graphics.setFont(colorsScheme.getFont(EditorFontType.PLAIN));
        graphics.setColor(color);

        // todo how to draw the textArea instead of the string?
        graphics.drawString(textArea.getText(), targetRegion.x, targetRegion.y + editor.getAscent());
    }
```

I tried to find a solution in the "documentation" of the IntelliJ platform and I searched the code for all implementations of `EditorCustomElementRenderer` but that did not help.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Could you please share the answer? I'm having so many different problems with this API. It's quite unintuitive/complex and filled with edge cases for inlay hints of code suggestions. :(